# Forward files from internal server to HTTP request

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, file-transfer

Maybe the title I have does not reflect my Question 100% but I will try to make it clearer. [That is how our system is right now.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NIzwW.png)


We have an Webserver that is public on the internet and the Webserver that has access to a Fileserver. We would like without having files on the Webserver the client to be able to download files from the Fileserver. Is there any technology available for these kind of requests? 

We are using **ASP. NET WebForms**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of any Framework that would do this but I implemented something similar. In our case we have a list of the files that users should be able to download in a database but you could simply use System.IO.Directory to query for the available files in a certain folder yourself. It's also required that the application runs in an application pool that has an identity (User) that is allowed to access the fileshare.

The actual download is implemented as an ASP.Net WebHandler (.ashx-File). When the user hits that Handler I basically do something like this in the ProcessRequest method:

```
string fileName = "\\\\myServer\\folder\\file.pdf";
byte[] fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName);

context.Response.Clear();
context.Response.ClearHeaders();
context.Response.ClearContent();

context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(fileName));
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileContent.Length.ToString());
context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileContent);
```

Of course if you are dealing with bigger files you might want to not load the entire file into memory but rather read in chunks and make multiple calls to BinaryWrite. You also should set the ContentType to a MIME-Type that fits your file type so it gets handled correctly by the clients browser.